Cloudinary does not allow me to upload multiple images
// image-upload.tsx

"use client";
import { useState, useEffect } from "react";
import { Button } from "./button";
import { ImagePlusIcon, Trash } from "lucide-react";
import Image from "next/image";
import { CldUploadWidget } from "next-cloudinary";

interface ImageUploadProps {
 disabled?: boolean;
 onChange: (value: string) => void;
 onRemove: (value: string) => void;
 value: string[];
}

const ImageUpload: React.FC<ImageUploadProps> = ({
 disabled,
 onChange,
 onRemove,
 value,
}) => {
const [isMounted, setIsMounted] = useState(false);

useEffect(() => {
 setIsMounted(true);
}, []);

const onUpload = (result: any) => {
 onChange(result.info.secure_url);
};

if (!isMounted) {
 return null;
}
return (
 <div>
   <div className="mb-4 flex items-center gap-4">
     {value.map((url) => (
       <div
         key={url}
         className="relative w-[200px] h-[200px] rounded-md overflow-hidden"
       >
         <div className="z-10 absolute top-2 right-2">
           <Button
             type="button"
             onClick={() => onRemove(url)}
             variant="destructive"
             size="icon"
           >
             <Trash className="h-4 w-4" />
           </Button>
          </div>
          <Image fill className="object-cover" alt="Image" src={url} />
         </div>
       ))}
      </div>
      <CldUploadWidget
       onSuccess={onUpload}
       options={{
       multiple: true,
       maxFiles: 5,
       sources: ["local", "url", "unsplash"],
      }}
      uploadPreset="djrccgni"
     >
      {({ open }) => {
       const onClick = () => {
         open();
      };  

      return (
        <Button
          type="button"
          disabled={disabled}
          variant="secondary"
          onClick={onClick}
        >
          <ImagePlusIcon className="h-4 w-4 mr-2" />
          Upload an Image
        </Button>
      );
     }}
   </CldUploadWidget>
 </div>
 );
};
export default ImageUpload;

// product-form.tsx

"use client";

import ImageUpload from "@/components/ui/image-upload";
const formSchema = z.object({
 images: z.object({ url: z.string() }).array(),
})

interface ProductFormProps {
 initialData:
 | (Product & {
    images: Image[];
   })
 | null;

type ProductFormValues = z.infer<typeof formSchema>;

export const ProductForm: React.FC<ProductFormProps> = ({
initialData
}) => {
const params = useParams();
const router = useRouter();
const origin = UseOrigin();
const [open, setOpen] = useState(false);
const [loading, setLoading] = useState(false);

const form = useForm<ProductFormValues>({
 resolver: zodResolver(formSchema),
 defaultValues: initialData
   ? {
       ...initialData,
    }
  : {
   
      images: [],
    },
});

const onSubmit = async (data: ProductFormValues) => {
 try {
   setLoading(true);
   if (initialData) {
     await axios.patch(
       `/api/${params.storeId}/products/${params.productId}`,
       data
     );
  } else {
    await axios.post(`/api/${params.storeId}/products`, data);
  }

  router.refresh();
  router.push(`/${params.storeId}/products`);
  toast.success(toastMessage);
 } catch (error) {
  toast.error("Oops! Something went wrong.");
 } finally {
  setLoading(false);
 }
};

const onDelete = async () => {
 try {
   setLoading(true);
   await axios.delete(`/api/${params.storeId}/products/${params.productId}`);
   router.refresh();
   router.push(`/${params.storeId}/products`);
   toast.success("Product deleted.");
 } catch (error) {
   toast.error("Oops! Something went wrong. ");
 } finally {
   setLoading(false);
   setOpen(false);
 }
};

return (
 <>
   <div className="flex items-center justify-between">
  
  <Form {...form}>
    <form
      onSubmit={form.handleSubmit(onSubmit)}
      className="space-y-8 w-full"
    >
      <FormField
        control={form.control}
        name="images"
        render={({ field }) => (
          <FormItem>
            <FormLabel>Images</FormLabel>
            <FormControl>
              <ImageUpload
                 value={field.value.map((image) => image.url)}
                 disabled={loading}
                 onChange={(url) => field.onChange([...field.value, {url}])}
                 onRemove={(url) => field.onChange([...field.value.filter((current) => 
                 current.url !== url)])}
              />
            </FormControl>
            <FormMessage />
          </FormItem>
        )}
      />

I am building an app using React and NextJS, and I have a form in which I upload an array of images via Cloudinary, but I am having a problem with Cloudinary because it doesn't allow me to upload more than one image. I checked their docs and it looks like since they deprecated onUpload and replaced it with onSuccess, when uploading multiple images, you have to use the options and add multiple: true to be able to upload more than one file. I did as they suggested and still, I am unable to upload more than one image.
Github repo: https://github.com/jeanmako/cloudinary-demo

Do you get any error messages you could share? A repro environment in CodeSandbox or a github repo would be helpful to debug further.

https://github.com/jeanmako/cloudinary-demo

@DannyV, I have added the Github repo to the question.
